# Is there zooming option in jqChart?

Tags: jquery, jqchart

I wonder if there is zoom option in jqChart?

Comment: Currently, there isn’t such option, but it is a part of the jqChart product roadmap. http://www.jqchart.com/ProductRoadmap.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jqChart component now has zoom option. You can check it here: http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/chart/

Disclamer: I work for jqChart.